# Script bat Uninstalling the old version and installing the new version of the program

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a script to uninstall an older, existing, version of proCertum CardManager, before installing a newer version.

The program is available in our environment in both 32bit and 64bit versions, *(eventually there will only be a 64bit version)*.

I need is:
-Check version of proCertum CardManager by Display Version
-if version 3.5.1.198 AND it is new version then GOTO :END
else GOTO :INSTALL

So far I have created a script but when I run it nothing happens. What am I missing?

Contents of the script:

```bash
@echo on
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%a IN ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\proCertum CardManager" /V DisplayVersion') DO (
    IF "%%a"=="DisplayVersion" SET "DisplayVersion=%%c"
    if %DisplayVersion%=="3.5.1.198" ( goto :END
        else (
            goto :INSTALL
        )

        FOR /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%a IN ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstal\proCertum CardManager" /V DisplayVersion') DO (
            IF "%%a"=="DisplayVersion" SET "DisplayVersion=%%c"
            if %DisplayVersion%=="3.5.1.198" ( goto :END
                else (
                    goto :INSTALL
                )

                :INSTALL
                REM Uninstall Older version  
                start /wait msiexec.exe /x {B96A7F3B-AF29-489A-AE84-1DDF5942971C} /qn

                REM Install latest version
                start /wait msiexec.exe /i "%~dp0proCertumCardManager-3.5.1.198-64-bit-pl.msi" /qn /quiet

                :END
```

I have created a script but when I run it nothing happens. Please indicate what is missing

My script now looks like this:

```bash
@echo off
for /f  "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (`wmic product where name^='proCertumCardManager' 2^>^&1`) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do set "result=%%~#"
)

if "%result%" equ "No Instance(s) Available." (
    goto :END 

if "%result%" neq "No Instance(s) Available." 
    goto :INSTALL_FULL

)

:INSTALL_FULL
reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{B96A7F3B-AF29-489A-AE84-1DDF5942971C} /v DisplayVersion
reg query HKLM\Software\wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{B96A7F3B-AF29-489A-AE84-1DDF5942971C} /v DisplayVersion

for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{B96A7F3B-AF29-489A-AE84-1DDF5942971C} /v DisplayVersion') do (

if %%i EQU 3.6.1.208 goto :END
if %%i NEQ 3.6.1.208 goto :INSTALL
)
:INSTALL
REM Uninstall Older version  
start /wait msiexec.exe /x {B96A7F3B-AF29-489A-AE84-1DDF5942971C} /qn


REM Install latest version
start /wait msiexec.exe /i "%~dp0proCertumCardManager-3.6.1.208-64-bit-pl.msi" /qn /quiet

:END
```

Comment: I read a little about the parameters "if "for" "goto" in cmd, I managed to write a script. Now I have a problem how to set the appropriate command so that the script in case it does not detect two defined values of "reg query" is to finish the task without taking any action.

Comment: I added a sequence to the code with the wmic command.
When the program is not installed the script works fine and goes to the :END value.
On the other hand, if the program is installed then the script doesn't want to go to the part where uninstall and install is performed.